# Как разрешить изменять текст который ввёл пользователь в JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing

Как сделать так, что бы пользователь мог вводить любой текст, а стирать только свой текст.
И да, между "системным" текстом нельзя вводить.

Помогите, как это сделать, или может есть библиотеки?

Comment: Можно попробовать создать JScrollPane с JLabel-ами и JTextField, и установить им одинаковый Border

Comment: @Agzam4 Не понял

Comment: Создаешь JScrollPane, туда в viewport устанавливаешь JPanel (с layout: BoxLayout Y_AXIS), и на эту jпанель добавляешь Jlabel-ы и JtextField у которых например setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5))